Not able to read nested element in Spark?
I am trying to read a dataframe which is created using nested jSON. Somehow i am not able to read the one of the nested key and get error.
val df=spark.read.json(Seq("""
    [{
        "testPlans": [{
            "attr1": "abc"
        }, {
            "attr2": "bac",
            "attr3": [{
                "uniqueId": "111"
            }]
        }]
    }]""").toDS())
    
    df.select("testPlans.attr1","testPlans.attr2","testPlans.attr3.uniqueId").show()

Error Message:
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'testPlans.`attr3`['uniqueId']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''uniqueId'' is of string type.;



Please don't post code/errors as screenshot. Copy paste the error message in your original post.

To access a nested array you need to explode it first
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("attr3", explode($"testPlans.attr3"))
  .select("testPlans.attr1", "testPlans.attr2", "attr3.uniqueId")
  .show()

+-----------+-----------+--------+
|      attr1|      attr2|uniqueId|
+-----------+-----------+--------+
|[abc, null]|[null, bac]|    null|
|[abc, null]|[null, bac]|   [111]|
+-----------+-----------+--------+

